# Problem with function that accepts (object or array, iterator)

Tags: javascript

I think my biggest question is regarding the parameter "iterator".
I'm guessing that it accepts a function.
Am I supposed to provide parameters for that function?

```
// Call iterator(value, key, collection) for each element of collection.
// Accepts both arrays and objects.

_.each = function(collection, iterator) 
{
  if (typeof collection=='object') 
  {
    for(let i=0; i<Object.keys(collection).length; i++) 
    {
      iterator(collection[i],Object.keys(collection)[i],collection);
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    for(let i=0; i<collection.length; i++) 
    {
      iterator(collection[i],i,collection);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hello @elderen, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide us code and ask specific question related to it. [mcve]

Comment: Your assumption might be incorrect - [an iterator is officially an object that implements the `next()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols). However, you might not be talking about the iteration protocol as defined in ES6 - a library could very well have its own iterator that is actually a function. Or an object but it requires different methods/signatures on it. It's hard to say without knowing exactly what you're talking about - please add relevant information like links, documentation, or code to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#forEach) and [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/#each) refer to this an an **iteratee** not iterator.  This is probably to help avoid confusion with javascript iterators.

The iteratee is a function the will be called for you. You defined the function and the `each` will call it for each item in the collection. The documentation will tell you what the signature of the function should look like. For instance `underscore` will pass `(element, index, list)` to the function for each item. It's up to you to write the function and decide what to do with those parameters.

For example from Lodash:

```
_.forEach([1, 2], function(value) {
    console.log(value);
 });
```

The iteratee is the anonymous function, that's only using the `value` parameter.

Comment: "*This is probably to help avoid confusion with javascript iterators.*" still, I always found the name confusing - *iteratee* sounds like the current element you're operating on. Basically `for (iteratee of someCollection)`. Instead it's actually the operation (or part of it) performed on that element - acting as the body of the loop, if you will. I don't like either `iteratee` or `iterator` for a name here. But I also don't have a suggestion for anything better - naming things is [one of the two hard things in computer science](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096).